# How to get the html table value row by row and perform some calculations on values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to fetch first table value row by row and show these values in a dynamically created row with the same name in table 2.

I got first table value row by row by I cannot show these value in row by row in the table. In table 2 it shows the value with last row value it cannot insert value in next row but it can override the first-row value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {

    var idx = $(this).closest('tr').index();

    $("#tbUser").find("tr").eq(idx).remove();
    $("#tbUsers").find("tr").eq(idx - 1).remove();
  });



  $("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnAdd', function() {

    $("#tbUser").append("<tr class='item'><td>Pad</td><td id='selection'>0.000307</td><td><input type='text' name='BottomHoleRate' id='BottomHoleRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='CleanVolume' id='CleanVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='BottomHoleConcentration' id='BottomHoleConcentration'></td><td>v 2.2</td><td><input type='text' name='Chemvol' id='Chemvol'></td><td><button class='btnAdd'>Add</button></td><td><button class='btnDelete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
    $("#tbUsers").append("<tbody><tr><td><input type='text' name='StageTime' id='StageTime' value=''></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryRate' id='SlurryRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='CleanRate' id='CleanRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='BlenderConcentration' id='BlenderConcentration'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolumeRate' id='ProppantVolumeRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantMassRate' id='ProppantMassRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantAVG' id='ProppantAVG'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantStageMass' id='ProppantStageMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeMass' id='ProppantCumulativeMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolume' id='ProppantVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeVolume' id='ProppantCumulativeVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryStageVolume' id='SlurryStageVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryCumulativeVolume' id='SlurryCumulativeVolume'></td></tr></tbody>");

    $("#tbUsers2").append("<tr><td>Pad</td></tr>");
    $("#tbUsers3").append("<tr><td>Pad</td></tr>");

  });
});


$('button').on('click', function() {

  $("tr.item").each(function() {
    var BottomHoleRate = $(this).find("input[name='BottomHoleRate']").val(),
      CleanVolume = $(this).find("input[name = 'CleanVolume']").val();
    bhc = $(this).find("input[name = 'BottomHoleConcentration']").val();
    Chemvol = $(this).find("input[name = 'Chemvol']").val();
    // SlurryStageVolume=document.getElementById('SlurryStageVolume').value;

    SlurryRate = BottomHoleRate;
    blenderconcentration = bhc;
    ProppantAVG = document.getElementById('selection').innerText;

    proppant_stage_mass = CleanVolume * bhc;
    pro_cum_mass = proppant_stage_mass;
    proppant_vol = proppant_stage_mass * ProppantAVG;
    pro_cum_vol = proppant_vol;
    slurry_stage_vol = CleanVolume * (1 + ProppantAVG * bhc);

    slurry_cum_vol = slurry_stage_vol;

    cleanrate = SlurryRate / (1 + ProppantAVG + bhc);
    stage = slurry_stage_vol / SlurryRate;

    proppant_vol_rate = cleanrate * bhc * ProppantAVG;
    proppant_mass_rate = cleanrate * bhc;
    chem_rate1 = Chemvol * cleanrate;
    chem_vol = Chemvol * CleanVolume;
    document.getElementById('StageTime').value = stage;
    document.getElementById('SlurryRate').value = SlurryRate;
    document.getElementById('CleanRate').value = cleanrate;
    document.getElementById('BlenderConcentration').value = blenderconcentration;
    document.getElementById('ProppantVolumeRate').value = proppant_vol_rate;
    document.getElementById('ProppantMassRate').value = proppant_mass_rate;
    document.getElementById('ProppantAVG').value = ProppantAVG;
    document.getElementById('ProppantStageMass').value = proppant_stage_mass;
    document.getElementById('ProppantCumulativeMass').value = pro_cum_vol;
    document.getElementById('ProppantVolume').value = proppant_vol;
    document.getElementById('ProppantCumulativeVolume').value = pro_cum_vol;
    document.getElementById('SlurryStageVolume').value = slurry_stage_vol;
    document.getElementById('SlurryCumulativeVolume').value = slurry_cum_vol;
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tbUser" class="tblUser" name="tblUser">
    <tr>
      <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
      <td><button class="btnAdd">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Stage Name</th>
      <th>Proppant Selection</th>
      <th>Bottom Hole Rate</th>
      <th>Clean Volume</th>
      <th>Bottom Hole Concentration</th>
      <th>Quality</th>
      <th>Chem 1 Vol/Vol</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 2</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers">
    <tr>
      <th>Stage Time (min)</th>
      <th>Slurry Rate</th>
      <th>Clean Rate</th>
      <th>Blender Concentration</th>
      <th>Proppant Volume Rate</th>
      <th>Proppant Mass Rate</th>
      <th>Proppant AVG</th>
      <th>Proppant Stage Mass</th>
      <th>Proppant Cumulative Mass</th>
      <th>Proppant Volume</th>
      <th>Proppant Cumulative Volume</th>
      <th>Slurry Stage Volume</th>
      <th>Slurry Cumulative Volume</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 3</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers2">
    <tr>
      <th>Chem rate 1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h2>table 4</h2>
  <table id="tbUsers3">
    <tr>
      <th>Chem Volume 1</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
  <button>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is that you have duplicate **ID**s. **The ID should be unique and used only once on a page.** You should replace them with **class**es like this (while you adding them):

```
$("#tbUsers").append("<tbody><tr><td><input type='text' name='StageTime' class='StageTime' value=''></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryRate' class='SlurryRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='CleanRate' class='CleanRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='BlenderConcentration' class='BlenderConcentration'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolumeRate' class='ProppantVolumeRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantMassRate' class='ProppantMassRate'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantAVG' id='ProppantAVG'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantStageMass' class='ProppantStageMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeMass' class='ProppantCumulativeMass'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantVolume' class='ProppantVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='ProppantCumulativeVolume' class='ProppantCumulativeVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryStageVolume' class='SlurryStageVolume'></td><td><input type='text' name='SlurryCumulativeVolume' class='SlurryCumulativeVolume'></td></tr></tbody>");
```

Then you should fill the values like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('SlurryRate')[0].value = SlurryRate;
document.getElementsByClassName('SlurryRate')[1].value = SlurryRate;
```

NOTE:

`document.getElementsByClassName('SlurryRate')`
returns an array of elements, so you have to fill all the elements.

Of course, you can write a nice function to handle this in a cleaner way, however this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with duplicate ID. **Any element on the page must have a unique ID. If there are duplicate ID for elements, the element at the top of the DOM gets selected every time.**

You have also put the `name` attribute for each input field. You can avoid adding `class`. The following snippet selects the **last element in DOM for the given `name`** and effectively, the last row -

`$(input[name="NameOfYourField"]).last().val(ValueOfThisField);`

I have implemented the above for some of your input fields in this pen

https://codepen.io/xpri/pen/PyJMNO

You can see your expected behavior in this.

Comment: i am checking the code but it can work properly some of fileds are empty.we want to fill all row through loop iteration

Comment: `I have implemented the above **for some** of your input fields in this pen`...you had too many fields, and I was feeling a bit lazy :p

Comment: You can understand and extend the presented code snippet very easily to all other fields...all your fields have `id` and `name` attributes set to them. You only have to copy-paste this snippet and replace the `name` value in the jquery selector and the javascript variable name containing the value in the `val()` part.

Comment: i will do for all inputs but it show first row  with empty value

Comment: simple my problem is that when we get the first row value then we want to show these values in first row of another table and then we get the value of 2nd row then values shows in 2nd row

Comment: In my example you first click the Add button, in both tables a blank row appears. Then you add values in the first table's row and again click the Add button. This time another row appears in both tables but in the first row of the 2nd table you've got calculated values. Now you fill the second row of first table and click Add button..2nd row of 2nd table gets filled with calculated values...if this is not what you want please try explaining a bit more..

Comment: i want that if user create 2 or more rows in table1 then we fetch these row value and perform calculation on row by row value and show first row value in first row,2nd row value in 2nd row and so on in table 2.